# make-kpkg not working in Fedora 20

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, fedora20

I have been working with Linux kernel, compiling and inserting modules, in my custom kernels. Previously I had Ubuntu where I had been working with my custom kernel and all the commands for compiling and installing kernel worked like a charm once I had installed all the required libraries.

Now I have switched over to Fedora 20, here I want to install my custom kernel and for that I downloaded all possible kernel tools, namely, `Kernel Development` `Kernel Tools` these are group installs and other libraries that I downloaded were ia32 libraries (as I am working on 64-bit OS), kernel-devel package. Still I am not able to work with `make-kpkg` command. It says `bash: make-kpkg: command not found...`.

I googled out and did everything I could.

Can anyone get me out of this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make-kpkg` is a Debian kernel packaging tool. It does not exist on RHEL family distributions, such as Fedora.

Please refer to the Fedora documentation page "[Building a custom kernel](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel)" for the correct procedure. (I have not reproduced it here as it is rather long, and I'm not sure how far you may have gotten.)

Answer (score 0):

The make-kpkg tool is part of the 'kernel-package' package on Debian systems.  It is a Debian tool to produce debian package files.  Ubuntu is based on Debian and has this tool.  However, Fedora uses a different system to manage packages. So, make-kpkg would not be available on Fedora.